# Removing layer from data source in web experience

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-experience-builder

I have a web experience with a section that contains five maps. Every map have a part of a power line in it.

- Map 1 has a power line from A to B
- Map 2 has a power line from B to C
- Map 3 has a power line from C to D
- Map 4 has a power line from D to E
- Map 5 has all lines

My web experience is set up in a way where I have added the same map with all lines five times, renamed the to its respective area, and filtered the data. The problem is that in Map 3, I have a lot of additional layers that I only need for that map.

Is there a way to remove the layers in the data source?

I have only been able to toggle them off, but they can be toggled on again in the layers menu.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but you can turn off the "layers menu" as you call it so the user of the web experience cannot change which layers they can view. If you select the map in the web experience editor, under content>tools, you can uncheck "layers". That way the layers are fixed.